# RadioGroup/Button align

Tags: android, radio-button, android-xml, radio-group

I'm trying to make an app with radio button which list them downwards which I have done. But I want them to be in the center of the page what ever screen size with the buttons all aligned. I've tried but its not in the center in all devices and I tried changing it but then the buttons wasn't align. Any help would be great. Thanks.

Code

```
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/backgroundp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingLeft="10dip"
android:paddingRight="10dip"
android:paddingTop="20dip" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
    android:text="@string/question1"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
    android:src="@drawable/square" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/q1_group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="30dip"
    android:paddingLeft="60dip" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/q1a1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="@string/shapetr"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/q1a2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="@string/shapeci"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/q1a3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="@string/shapesq"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Comment: What is the parent layout?

Comment: Ill add it now, sorry.

Comment: Change the `height` of `RadioGroup` to `match_parent

Comment: Thanks for trying, but it does nothing. But thanks

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I didn't notice the other Views. I have posted an answer that should work

Answer (score 0):

use the layout_gravity of parent layout

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you are looking for

```
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="10dip"
android:paddingRight="10dip"
android:paddingTop="20dip" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
    android:text="question1"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:layout_above="@id/ivId" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivId"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="10dip"
    android:layout_above="@id/q1_group" />

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/q1_group"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:paddingBottom="30dip"
    android:paddingLeft="60dip" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/q1a1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="shapetr"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/q1a2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="shapeci"
        android:textSize="25sp" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/q1a3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:text="shapesq"
        android:textSize="25sp" />
</RadioGroup>

      </RelativeLayout>
```

I changed the parent `layout` to `RelativeLayout`. This way, the `RadioGroup` could be centered with

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

then I placed the other `Views` above with

```
android:layout_above="@id/idOfViewBelow"
```

which meant I had to give your `ImageView` an `id` which all `Views` really should have most of the time

Comment: Getting error on   android:layout_above="@id/q1_group"  and      android:layout_above="@id/ivId"

Comment: Error: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/q1_group').

Comment: try cleaning your project

Comment: Ok, then I should have stuck with my first suggestion. Change to `@+id` Notice the "+".

Comment: Sorry, Was business for a seconded. The image does not show up now and all the strings have turn to text. But I think I may be able to fix it. Give me 5 mins, busy for 5mins

Comment: Ok, no problem. Just curious. I had to change the strings and baackground resources to test on my machine. Just put the references to your `string` and `drawable` resources back in

Comment: Yes. I've done it but now everything is in the top left corner and the TextView is not there

Comment: That's strange, it worked for me. You changed `LinearLayout` to `RelativeLayout` and added this line `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to your `RadioGroup`?

Comment: Yes. Thanks for all help so far

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34007/discussion-between-codemagic-and-user2407147)